# Regex allowing a space character in Java

Tags: java, regex

Hey all, so I'm trying to allow some text input which goes through a regex check before it's sent off. I want the text to only include A-Z, 0-9, and the space " " character. Here is my code now:

```
if(!title.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+") {
    //fail
}
else {
    //success
}
```

However this still gives the `//fail` result when I input something like "This is a test"

Any ideas? Thanks all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're not including the space in the Regex. Try the following:

```
if (!title.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"))
```

Comment: Ah... I thought the _ denoted a " ". So simply `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+` should work?

Comment: Yes. `_` is the literal underscore. Which it seems like you don't want. I have updated my example.

Answer (score 2):

`\s` allows for any ASCII whitespace character. Consider using that rather than " ".

```
if(!title.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+")) {
    //fail
}
else {
    //success
}
```

Comment: No, `\s` is only for 7-bit data.  It doesn’t work on Java’s native character set.

Comment: That's news to me! I guess I should be a little more careful.

Comment: That’s the problem with the standard Java regex library. It doesn’t work with Java’s own character set! You have to JNI over to ICU’s to get anything that works properly — by which I mean, as a bare minimum, complies with the Level 1 requirements for basic Unicode functionality which are  spelled out [UTS#18 Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/). Java doesn’t meet most of those, let alone anything further up in Level 2 or Level 3 land. That’s why Google does the JNI-to-ICU thing for Android. They need Unicode support.

Comment: I think that `\\s` will work instead of `\s`.