# How to allow a space in RegEx?

Tags: java, regex, space

I have a following java code:

```
public boolean isValidFirstName() {
    return tbFName.getText().trim().matches("^(\\w+)")
            & tbFName.getText().trim() != "";
}
```

It verifying  the text with given `RegEx`. I want to allow the user to add a space in `RegEx`. I am newbie in regex.How should i do that?

Comment: Be aware that `\w` only matches ASCII letters (but also digits and underscores), so it may not be a good choice for validating a name. Not that that's a good idea in the first place...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex allowing a space character in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601754/regex-allowing-a-space-character-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add space as a valid character:

```
public boolean isValidFirstName() {
    return tbFName.getText().trim().matches("^(\\w| )+)")
            & tbFName.getText().trim() != "";
}
```

Here I am using alternation (with the `|` character) - so either `\w` or spaces are allowed.

Comment: With `[\\w ]+` one less character to write :)

Comment: @xdazz: he should `trim()` before regex checking.

Comment: @Oded I think it's not good because string can starts from space.

Comment: Are you certain `\\w` will mean the same _within_ a character class?

Comment: @Pepelac - The OP didn't specify _where_ spaces are allowed, only that they should be allowed.

Comment: @Oded but i think that is strange if your FirstName starts with whitesapce. Dr. Mr. WhiteSpaceJohn)

Comment: @Pepelac - Fair point, but my point is that without an _exact_ requirement from the OP, this answers the question. The OP didn't say that the name should exclude whitespace at the start or end.

Comment: @Oded Ok. Let it be so. I think soon we get new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isValidFirstName() {
    return tbFName.getText().trim().matches("^[\\w ]+")
            & tbFName.getText().trim() != "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to match a first name (without special characters like é or è) use the following regexp : `^[a-zA-Z_ -]+`