# Regex for ONE-or-more letters/digits And ZERO-or-more spaces

Tags: java, regex

I want to allow 0 or more white spaces in my string and one or more A-Z or a-z or 0-9 in my string.

[Regex allowing a space character in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601754/regex-allowing-a-space-character-in-java?rq=1)

suggests `[0-9A-Za-z ]+`.

I doubt that, this regex matches patterns having zero or more white spaces.

What to do to allow 0 or more whitespaces anywhere in the string and one or more characters anywhere in the string.

Will this work? `([0-9A-Za-z]+)([ ]*)`

Comment: By any convenient chance, do you know the first letter is not a whitespace?

Comment: why do you have doubts? It will match "blanks" - if you want accept all whitespaces, use `[0-9A-Za-z\s]+`

Comment: `([0-9A-Za-z]+)([ ])*` will require that it cannot start with a space.

Comment: @dognose : Edited. I meant zero or more spaces.

Comment: `^(.*\p{Blank}?\p{Alnum}+.*\p{Blank}?)$` this will do it.

Comment: @vvid: Zero or more spaces... Well, the regex covers EVERYTHING except the case of `zero whitespaces` - for that, use an empty-string check and you got all you need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
([ ]*+[0-9A-Za-z]++[ ]*+)+
```

This is 0 or more spaces, followed by at least 1 alphanum char, followed by 0 or more spaces

^^ that whole thing at least once.

Using Pshemo's idea of possessive quantifiers to speed up the regex.

Comment: +1 While not as fancy as the look-ahead options, this is certainly easier to understand!

Comment: Does this check for spaces between characters? Eg:"Good morning J"?

Comment: @wid absolutely. `Good` will be matched by the `[0-9A-Za-z]+`, then since it doesn't work, it will go to the beginning of the group again and match the space with `[ ]*`, and repeat.

Comment: @Quincunx Hmm, you're right. I don't know much about regex interpreters. Could that potentially be slower since it has to recheck for spaces after every char?

Comment: @Quincunx Not exactly. What if spaces would be placed at end of String?

Comment: @Pshemo Then Cruncher's regex won't work. `([ ]*[0-9A-Za-z])+` is equivalent to `([ ]*[0-9A-Za-z]+)+` (that is what I meant in my comment)

Comment: @Pshemo Ah, you're right, in that case mine doesn't work as is. I have to put the space back into the end

Comment: @Cruncher Or just do `([ ]*[0-9A-Za-z]*)+` or even `([ ]?[0-9A-Za-z]?)+`

Comment: @Cruncher Yep. Also `([foo]+)+` smells like catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @Quincunx `([ ]*[0-9A-Za-z]*)+` will match empty

Comment: Fine, then `[0-9A-Za-z ]([ ][0-9A-Za-z]|[0-9A-Za-z]|[ ])+`

Comment: @Quincunx at that `([0-9A-Za-z ]+[ ]*)+` works as well. There's a tonne of variations of this actually.

Comment: My thought is that avoiding nested `*` and `+` might speed up the regex.

Comment: @Quincunx yeah, I actually like donut's the best, although you have to think about it for a few seconds first

Comment: If you want to speed up this regex you can use [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `([ ]*+[0-9A-Za-z]++[ ]*+)+`.

Comment: @Pshemo In this case, the possessive quantifiers shouldn't change the language right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "change the language", but they will not change set of matched/accepted Strings.

Comment: @Pshemo Well, any regex string represents a formal language (specifically a regular one) which is defined by which strings are and are not in it. Put more specifically, do the positive quantifiers reject or accept any string that it wouldn't have before?

Comment: I pressed enter key to fast. See my updated earlier comment :)

Comment: @Pshemo, Quincunx: This works. If I have another constraint like the string must have atleast one digit and atleast one alpha, I tried doing `([ ]*+[0-9]++[A-Za-z]++[ ]*+)+`. That doesn't work. What is wrong here?

Comment: @wid In that case you need to use [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanisms like in [M42 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23091541/1393766).

Comment: ` ^(?=.*\\s*)(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[a-zA-z]+)[a-zA-z0-9 ]+$ ` - I used this for the above constraint. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

> The most simple answer

`*` means `zero or more` equivalent to  `{0,}`

`+` means `one or more` equivalent to  `{1,}`

so look at this

`[A-Z]+` means `at least one Capital Letter`, can be written as `[A-Z]{1,}`

`[!@#$%&].` means you can have these Special Characters `zero or more times` can be written as `[!@#$%&]{0,}`

sorry but

> the `purpose` of this `answer` to be `as Simple as possible`

Answer (score 7):

You can try also this :

```
  ^[0-9A-Za-z ]*[0-9A-Za-z]+[ ]*$
```

Comment: Smart! I seriously doubted this before trying it.

Answer (score 4):

Use lookahead:

```
^(?=.*\s*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

Comment: This answer might benefit from some additional explanation if you have time.

Comment: `(?=.*\s*)` seems redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Before looking at the other answers, I came up with doing it in two regexes:

```
boolean ok = (myString.matches("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$")  &&  !myString.matches("^ *$"));
```

This matches one-or-more letters/digits *and* zero-or-more spaces, but *not* only spaces (or nothing).

It could be made efficient by pre-creating a single matcher object for each regex:

```
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class OnePlusLetterDigitZeroPlusSpace  {
   //"": Unused search string, to reuse the matcher object
   private static final Matcher mtchr1PlusLetterDigitSpc = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-z0-9 ]+$").matcher("");
   private static final Matcher mtchr0PlusSpc = Pattern.compile("^ *$").matcher("");
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      test("");
      test(" ");
      test("a");
      test("hello ");
      test(" hello ");
      test("hello there");
   }
   private static final void test(String to_search)  {
      System.out.print("\"" + to_search + "\": ");
      if(mtchr1PlusLetterDigitSpc.reset(to_search).matches()  &&  !mtchr0PlusSpc.reset(to_search).matches())  {
         System.out.println("good");
      }  else  {
         System.out.println("BAD");
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java OnePlusLetterDigitZeroPlusSpace
"": BAD
" ": BAD
"a": good
"hello ": good
" hello ": good
"hello there": good
```

Interesting regex question of the day.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking that the string (`s`) satisfies this condition (note: let `c∈s` mean `c∈{x|x is a character in s}`. Also, `[]` represent regex character classes):

```
(∀c∈s (c∈[0-9A-Za-z ])) ∧ (∃c∈s ∋ c∈[0-9A-Za-z])
```

Consider the negation:

```
¬((∀c∈s c∈[0-9A-Za-z ]) ∧ (∃c∈s ∋ c∈[0-9A-Za-z]))
⇔
(∃c∈s ∋ c∉[0-9A-Za-z ]) ∨ (∀c∈s c∉[0-9A-Za-z])
⇔
(∃c∈s ∋ c∈[^0-9A-Za-z ]) ∨ (∀c∈s c∈[^0-9A-Za-z])
```

So now we want to construct a regex that either contains a non-alphanumeric and non-space character or consists only of non-alphanumeric characters.

The first is easy: `[^0-9A-Za-z ]`.
The second is like unto it: `^[^0-9A-Za-z]*$`

Combine them together to get: `[^0-9A-Za-z ]|^[^0-9A-Za-z]*$`

Now we need to negate this regex. Obviously, we could just do `(?![^0-9A-Za-z ]|^[^0-9A-Za-z]*$)`. Or we could manually negate the regex:

`[^0-9A-Za-z ]` becomes `^[0-9A-Za-z ]*$`
`^[^0-9A-Za-z]*$` becomes `[0-9A-Za-z]`. (note: we could easily have arrived here from the beginning)

But now we need to combine them with AND, not OR:

Since `[0-9A-Za-z]` is a subset of `[0-9A-Za-z ]`, we can simply do this:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z ]*[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z ]*$
```

Note that we can simplify it down to:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z ]*[0-9A-Za-z][ ]*$
```

This just requires that the character that matches `[0-9A-Za-z]` is the last character that could do so. We could also do

```
^[ ]*[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z ]*$
```

Which would require that the character that matches `[0-9A-Za-z]` is the first character that could do so.

So now we're done. We can either use one of those or `(?![^0-9A-Za-z ]|^[^0-9A-Za-z]*$)`.

<sub>Note: `String#match` acts as if the regex is `^ + regex + $` (where `+` is concatenation). This can throw a few things off.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    if (subjectString.matches("(?i)^(?=.*\\s*)(?!.*_)(?=.*[\\w]+)[\\w ]+$")) {
        // String matched entirely
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**Or Simply:**

```
^(.*\p{Blank}?\p{Alnum}+.*\p{Blank}?)$
```

[Example](http://fiddle.re/ndwdk)

Comment: I've never seen a try/catch for a regular expression syntax failure.  Should that be necessary..?  The only case I can think of is a memory-leak/timeout caused by catastrophic backtracing..but I don't think that would through a `PatternSyntaxException`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing the format before using in production code?

Comment: @Sam I normally do, but this way I can catch it faster if I don't.

Comment: Fair enough, continue on.