# How to restrict more than one whitespace in Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex

A validation to be developed for a JavaFX text field where single whitespace is allowed but more than one whitespace is not be allowed.

> For example,  "Apple Juice" -- correct "Apple  Juice" -- incorrect
>   should be restricted

```
if (title.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"))
```

Found couple of links but not meeting my requirement. I believe that it is more of a logical tweak.

[Whitespace Matching Regex - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java)

[Regex allowing a space character in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601754/regex-allowing-a-space-character-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (title.matches([a-zA-z]+[ ][a-zA-Z]+))
```

- The first `[a-zA-z]+` checks for any characters before the space.
- The `[ ]` checks for exactly one space.
- The second `[a-zA-z]+` checks for any characters after the space.

---

Note: This will match only if the space is present in between the string. If you want to match strings like `Abcd<space>` or `<space>Abcd`, (I used `<spcace>` as SO does not allow two spaces to be present simultaneously) then you can replace the `+`s with `*`s., i.e.,

```
if (title.matches([a-zA-z]*[ ][a-zA-Z]*))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
if ("Apple Juice".matches("\\w+ \\w+")) {
 .......
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better find more than a single whitespace and negate the result:

```
if(!title.trim().matches("\s{2,}"))
```

, see java.util.regex.Pattern javadoc for the syntax. The string is first trimmed, so you don't need to check for non-whitespace characters. If you don't do the trim() operation, leading and trailing whitespace will also be considered.